# Realm-js Querying on timeStamp does not work

Tags: sql, react-native, realm, realm-js

This is with reference to `https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/tutorial-query-language.html`

I am not looking for variable substitution syntax as mentioned in the documentation.

So i have a date field by the name `createDate`, and i am trying to query on the same.
The filter query looks like `createDate = ${someDate}`, where `somedate` is in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD@HH:mm:ss'`, i also tried `==` instead of `=` in the query, but this simply does not work;

Comment: If you think you found a bug, please report it to https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/new. But please provide a very concrete full example of what doesn't work (preferable a gist)

Answer (score 1):

its hard to say without seeing how you're actually writing the query, but it could be how you're constructing it. maybe try

```
    filtered('createDate = $0', someDate)
```

using a placeholder variable ($0) solves query problems in realm for me